# Moving the WinForm through coding/pressing a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I was looking for an easy way of moving the form when the user presses a button. I'm making an rpg game and when the player attacks/gets attacked I want the Form to sort of "shake" a little, meaning moving it from left to right a few times or something along those lines.

Thanks for any answers, Joe.

Comment: Add a click handler to the button, and move the form by changing its position?  It's unclear what the issue is?  Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Try this: `private async Task ShakeForm(Form form, int speed, int times) { for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) { form.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => form.Left -= 4)); await Task.Delay(speed); form.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => form.Left += 8)); await Task.Delay(55); form.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => form.Left -= 4)); } }` and call it from somewhere with `Task.Run(() => ShakeForm(this, 120, 5));` for example.

Comment: You could also add [FlashWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindow).

Comment: @Jimi That looks like it could be submitted as an answer.  (Referring to both of your comments).

Comment: @Amy I prefer to close it. As it is, it's not a good question, IMO. Maybe the OP will try the *sample* and maybe they'll ask a more interesting question, as *Why FlashWindow doesn't work in the `async` method?*.

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, I see your reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call this method from a button click event or put this inside the event method itself -

```
    public void ShakeForm()
        {
            var original = this.Location;
            var rnd = new Random(1454);
​
            const int shake_amplitude = 10;
​
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                Location = new Point(original.X + rnd.Next(-shake_amplitude, shake_amplitude), original.Y + rnd.Next(-shake_amplitude, shake_amplitude));
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
            Location = original;
        }
```